# Substring from a sql query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Friends,

I need to substring a text value from a query result. In my example results, I would like to parse the numeric value where it precedes the letters "MG" or "MCG". These are dose amounts that I'm trying to get.

Example Data:

```
PEGASYS 180 MCG/0.5 ML SYRI
INCIVEK 375 MG TABLET
RIBA-PAK TAB 800MG/DAY T/R
```

I believe I can do it by finding the index position of MG, and then substring from there. Not sure exactly how to though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: PLease tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: In these types of free text fields, you'll find that you need a large number of rules to pluck out what you need, and these quickly proliferate and get incredibly complex. To just build rules for the three example cases is pretty awful. What options do you have for creating stored procedures or adding a column to the existing table? I could pose an answer which satisfies those three cases but it will be terribly complex and not of any use for any other cases.

Comment: I can write a proc, but I wouldn't be able to add another column to the table.

Comment: I actually figured it out if anyone is interested. This is the solution I implemented

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. This is what I implemented. Any feedback would be appreciated.

ALTER FUNCTION fn_GetDosageFromProductDescription
(
    @InputString VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Dosage VARCHAR(MAX), @Description VARCHAR(MAX), @Index INT

```
    -- Remove all spaces from string
    SELECT @Description = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', '')

    -- Find the index position for the first number within the string
    SELECT @Index = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Description)

    -- Get the substring starting at the position of the first number, then all remaining
    -- characters in string
    SELECT @Description = SUBSTRING(@Description, @Index, 100)

    -- Substring again from the the 0 of the first substring value, until we get to the
    -- next instance of a letter
    SELECT @Dosage = SUBSTRING(@Description, 0, PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%', @Description))
```

RETURN @Dosage
END
GO